# Is there a way to add a hyphen on a already existing tag? (R2D2 -> R2-D2)

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonyms

As discussed here :
[Change r2d2 tag to r2-d2](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/change-r2d2-tag-to-r2-d2) when we try to create the [correctly spelled](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/spelling-of-r2-d2-artoo-deetoo-and-c-3p0-see-threepio) "R2-D2" Tag we get this error message

> You are attempting to create the tag r2-d2 ; however the tag r2d2 already exists!

Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Can't you just eliminate the r2d2 tag? If this has mod approval, they should ne able to do that.

Comment: @BobCratchit So, eliminating the old tag is a solution? I thought the Tag will remain there even if there is no question attached to it.

Comment: With no questions, a tag will die in a day or two, and mods should be able to kill it instantly (I may be wrong; that could be a dev-only thing).

Comment: I think moderators can rename "r2d2" in "r2-d2."

Comment: @BobCratchit - Eliminating the r2d2 tag would require manually adding r2-d2 to all the questions.  *Don't* eliminate the tag if you want some form of that tag to exist later; you'll lose information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Moderators can create a tag through the tag synonym interface. I declared `r2-d2` as a synonym of `r2d2`, then merged `r2d2` into `r2-d2`, and presto, the tag has been renamed.

Comment: You can actually just straight up merge a tag into another that doesn't exist yet.  Saves a little time with the synonym.